# Object store key pointing to null even though it actually has a value

Tags: batch-processing, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio, persistent-object-store

I am processing some few thousand records using batch, before sending records to batch, I'm storing the key : value in object and retrieving them and processing, but for some records I'm facing the error.

'org.mule.extension.objectstore.api.TopLevelObjectStore$EnhancerByCGLIB$1f51aa05@1448fb70' doesn't contain any value for key '21725' and default value was not provided or resolved to a null value.",

Can someone please help me solve this problem

this is my flow and config setting of object store.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naGnN.png)

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). For Mule applications share the text XML of the configurations and flows.